# In C#, implement a check box to control the display of a message box when deleting a record from database

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am having trouble implementing a check box that when checked will make a message box pop up when the user is trying to delete a record.  When the check box is unchecked, the message box will not pop up and the record will be deleted right away.

Here is what I have currently without the checkbox implementation.

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
      int index = dataGridViewClients.CurrentRow.Index;
      if(MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete record?", "Message", 
         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)==DialogResult.Yes){
         ClientValidation.DeleteClient(clientVM.Clients[index]);
         }
     }
}
```

I am unsure how to put in the check box control within the method
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the checkbox checked property to the if statement like below, the checkbox checked value will be evaluated first and short circuit the or statement if not checked and not execute the messagebox.

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int index = dataGridViewClients.CurrentRow.Index;
        if(!CheckBox1.Checked ||
           MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete record?", "Message", 
           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)==DialogResult.Yes){
             ClientValidation.DeleteClient(clientVM.Clients[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wont this still make the MessageBox appear every time?

Comment: The or statement will be short circuited if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: Duh! Obviously, my bad.

Comment: Thanks. It works great.  Very simple but effective solution.

Comment: Hi @David Yim if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.  There is no obligation to do this.